# How to add recurring events pragmatically in DHTMLX Scheduler?

Tags: javascript, dhtml, dhtmlx

I'd like to add this event to my calendar

```
let eventID = scheduler.addEvent({
                        start_date: "2018-03-03 10:00:00",
                        end_date: "2018-03-10 11:00:00",
                        text: "words",
                        details: "",
                        rec_type: "week_1___1,2",
                    });
```

However, when I run through that part of my code I get an error in dhtmlxscheduler.js
`Cannot read property 'valueOf' of undefined`.  What's the proper way to add an event as recurring.  I've added the dependency js file for recurring events and specified the following in my init

```
    scheduler.config.details_on_create=true;
    scheduler.config.details_on_dblclick=true;
    scheduler.config.include_end_by = true;
    scheduler.config.repeat_precise = true;        
    var today = new Date(); 
    scheduler.init('scheduler_here',today, "week");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use addEvent for recurring events, the value of the start/end_date properties must have the Date type:

```
let eventID = scheduler.addEvent({
  id: '1',
  start_date: new Date(2018, 2, 3, 10), 
  end_date:   new Date(2018, 2, 10, 11),      
  text:"words",
  details: "",
  rec_type: "week_1___1,2",
  event_pid: "0",
  event_length: 60*60*4
})
```